# Access 2013 front end won't open

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I built and successfully split an Access 2013 db.  The front end worked fine for months up until I last used it a few months ago.  I recently went to open the front end but the Access window was frozen whereby everything (e.g., navigation pane, menus, controls, right click, etc.) was disabled, including the window control buttons to minimize, expand and close.  The only way to close the view was to right click the Access icon in the task bar or 'ctrl-alt-delete' to open task manager and force close the application.  I was met w/ similar results when attempting to open other versions of the linked front end; however, I can successfully open the back end and other Access db files that don't contain linked tables.  When I get the 'frozen' screen I can see my linked tables and other db objects in the navigation pane, but the pop-up login form does not display and the entire window behaves like it is inactive, similar to how it behaves when selecting items behind the active login form.

To confuse matters even worse, I have one user (User 1) who has the same user permissions as me who does not experience any of the problems I described above and can work within the front end as expected; in fact, he and I are the only active users as we are still in the developmental phase of our project.  One other layer of complexity, he tried to open the file w/ his network profile from my computer and ran into the same problems.  We have one other user who we've since tested this problem with and she experiences the same issues as me on both her laptop and PC.

So, I thought maybe it had to do with the 32-bit version I unknowingly had installed when my OS was re-installed last month since User 1 had the 64-bit version which could explain why he couldn't open from my computer.  BUT,  I still experienced the same issues after re-installing the 64-bit version on my computer.  I'm at a loss on where/how to proceed from here and my IT guys have done all they can to troubleshoot my problem as they are not familiar w/ Access and aren't much help at this point.

Anyone run into this problem before?  Thoughts or possible solutions? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you had the guy with the working version repair and compact his copy and send it to you?

Comment: Did you have the 64-bit version before? You and other users need to have the same version you created the database in.

Comment: Johnny B - Yes, I had him do exactly that.

Comment: jj - I did have the 64-bit version when I created the db, but when IT re-installed my MSO they put the 32-bit back on, I guess b/c they've had other issues in other programs w/ the 64-bit version.  I thought for sure that was going to be the fix, but it still didn't work until I removed the corrupt code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I disabled the code that prompted the login form and I was able to open the file.  Based on User 1's experience, we determined that he hadn't installed updates since I was last able to open the file.  As a result, we determined that an update I installed was not compatible w/ the aforementioned code resulting in the problems I described in my original post.  I will re-create the code that drives the form's login and keep an uncoded version as back-up in case we experience similar issues in future updates so that we can troubleshoot from within the db rather than be locked out as we were.